# Illegal conversion: can not convert from "java.lang.String" to "java.sql.Blob"

Tags: java, string, spring-boot, db2, blob

I am trying to insert a column into my Table which is defined as BLOB in DB2. In Java, I am trying to insert is as String.
So, its throwing an error as

```
Illegal conversion: can not convert from "java.lang.String" to "java.sql.Blob"
```

Here is my code :

```
 Object[] parameter = new Object[] { myTable.getMyNbr(),  myTable.getMyBlobField() };

   int parameterTypes[] = new int[] { Types.CHAR, Types.CHAR };
   
   StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
   
   final String INSERT_QUERY_TB= query.append("INSERT INTO My_TBL ( MY_NBR, MY_BLOBField(VALUES( ?, ?)"));

   int row = jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_QUERY_TB, parameter, parameterTypes);
```

What is the best way to insert this Blob field ? Is there some library to convert the String ?

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to convert the string to a byte array (which the `String` class already provides)? Btw, your query syntax looks wrong - the opening parenthesis after `MY_BLOBField` should be a closing one.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  byte[] ba= myTable.getMyBlobField().getBytes();  What should be its parameter type? Types.CHAR ?

Comment: Well, there is type `BLOB` which is what I'd try to use.